# Criação de Trigger

Tags: sql-server, query, trigger

Preciso desenvolver uma trigger em que qualquer alteração que ocorrer em um desses campos abaixo da tabela Tarefa, deverá enviar a informação da tarefa para a tabela Instrução.

**TABELA TAREFA**

```
TarefaID    Vencimento  Status      Caminho     ModuloID
  170123    2017-11-01       0    Desativar           71
```

**TABELA INSTRUÇÃO**

```
InstrucaoID     TarefaID
```

Resumindo. Sem sofrer nenhuma alteração na tarefa, a tabela instrução fica em branco, mas a partir do momento em que por exemplo, o vencimento da tarefa for alterada, de 01-11-17 para 03-11-17, a tarefaID vai para a tabela instrução, ficando dessa maneira.

**TABELA INSTRUÇÃO**

```
InstrucaoID     TarefaID
          1       170123
```

Comment: A dificuldade é em criar a `trigger` que insere na  tabela instrução?

Comment: a dificuldade é ao inserir na tabela instrução qualquer alteração em qualquer campo q eu citei na tabela tarefa.

Answer (score 2):

A trigger abaixo irá verificar qualquer alteração num destes campos (que você informou) e var inserir o valor do campo TarefaID na tabela Tarefas.

Inclui um cursor para que se for feita uma operação em lote, todos as ocorrências sejam registradas na tabela Tarefa.

Se qualquer exceção ocorrer, ela será capturada e exibida ao usuário de uma forma personalizada.

Obs: Assumi que sua tabela Tarefas possui o campo `InstrucaoID` como [`identity`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property);

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[TGR_TAREFA_AU]') AND type in (N'TR'))
    DROP TRIGGER [dbo].[TGR_TAREFA_AU]

GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TGR_TAREFA_AU]
ON [dbo].[TAREFA]
WITH ENCRYPTION
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @tTarefaID INT

    IF UPDATE(TarefaID) OR UPDATE(Vencimento) OR UPDATE(Status) OR UPDATE(Caminho) OR UPDATE(ModuloID)
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRAN

        BEGIN TRY
            DECLARE CURSOR_TAREFA CURSOR FOR 
            SELECT TarefaID FROM Inserted INS

            OPEN CURSOR_TAREFA

            FETCH NEXT FROM CURSOR_TAREFA INTO @tTarefaID
            WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO INSTRUCAO (TarefaID) VALUES(@tTarefaID)

                FETCH NEXT FROM CURSOR_TAREFA INTO @tTarefaID
            END

            CLOSE CURSOR_TAREFA
            DEALLOCATE CURSOR_TAREFA
            COMMIT
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK

            DECLARE @_ERROR_PROCEDURE VARCHAR(MAX)
            SET @_ERROR_PROCEDURE = 'Err Nº: ' + CAST(ERROR_NUMBER() AS VARCHAR(10)) +' | Severidade: '+ CAST(ERROR_SEVERITY() AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' | Estado: ' + CAST(ERROR_STATE() AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' | Procedure: '+ ISNULL(ERROR_PROCEDURE(),'') + ' | Linha: '+ CAST(ERROR_LINE() AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' | Erro: '+ ERROR_MESSAGE()   

            RAISERROR(@_ERROR_PROCEDURE,16,1)           
        END CATCH
    END
END
GO
```